# al insertar en github desde VS 2022 me sale "Error al insertar en el repositorio remoto. Consulte la ventana resultados para obtener más detalles"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Error al insertar en el repositorio remoto. Consulte la ventana resultados para obtener más detalles. En la ventana de resultado no sale ninguna informacion al respecto.

Answer (score 0):

Ese error me apareció y se solucionó fácil.
Lo que me ocurrió fue que había mandado la invitación de colaborador a mi cuenta del trabajo, pero me había olvidado aceptar la invitación.
**Acepté la invitación** y asunto solucionado.